# Restarting conversation state for testing proactive messages

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I've implemented proactive messages into my bot, however I'm very unsatisfied with the testing I've been able to do with this feature, since none of the tests I can think of actually "prove" I received a message proactively.

Basically, I want to send a message to members on Teams as soon as they install the bot, not as soon as they interact with it as is the traditional way. This is so when a member is added to an organisation, they are introduced to the bot without any user interaction.

To do this, I overrode OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync, and used that event to fire off a welcome message. When it comes to testing however, I can never be sure the welcome message fired because I opened the chat window, or because I installed the app.

For this reason, I cannot test it in the emulator, as that takes you straight to the chat which defeats the point. And I'm limited to 1 test per user account in Teams, because after you install the bot once, your conversation state is cached so it's never truly a fair test after the first interaction.

So my question is, is there any code that can clear my conversation, and re-add me so as to trigger OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync as if I'm a new user being added to the org? Or is there a better way of testing I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this asking the same question I am, I'll give you my solution, although it may be unavailable to the more casual dev that doesn't have resources behind them.

So my solution to this was to purchase a partner licence for Microsoft Power Apps, in there I can spin up sandbox environments for ms teams, which creates a whole environment in the context of a microsoft 'dataverse'. From there I could perform the tasks of an admin, and the tasks of the user and perform my tests all from 2 sandbox teams portals.

This is a bit more of an overkill solution than what I wanted, as the licence is not easy to get and grants me power to do lots of things I don't ever see myself doing, but it did indeed solve my issue.